# Where to store encrypted key of a prepulated sqlite in air application

Tags: android, sqlite, apache-flex, encryption, air

I have an air mobile application which bundled with a sqlite database which is pre-populated and encrypted with a key. Now since someone can reverse engineer and get the key, I need to know if there is better place to hide it somewhere on the device which can only accessed by my application, els is not an option i guess, because it also expose the key.

The key has to be same so I cant generate it on the device.

It might have been asked previously but I dont see any relevant answer for storing the key.

Thanks

Comment: ELS is pretty much the only option I guess although it have some weaknesses. For example, data is not encrypted on Android devices and theoretically can be accessed on a rooted device. Now I need to ask - how does ELS expose any keys ? I thought it is handled on the OS based on the user account ?

Comment: How do you suggest to use ELS when the key has to be a constant, predefined? how would I store it?

Comment: Oh, the key is hard-coded in the application as well ? Sorry, I have misread your question. Well, then the key is basically always exposed no matter what you do ? You can only make it harder to hack by encrypting the key etc?

Comment: So do you think it would add a security if I create an ane and put the key there, bit more secure I guess.

Comment: That won't give you any more security.  Someone who can reverse-engineer your key from the apk with it being in your AIR code can find it just as easily in ANE classes.  There's no way around this - you have to give the user the data in order for them to use it, you can't give it to them and still keep it under your control.

Comment: You can obfuscate your code to make it more time-consuming to extract the key, but that won't actually stop someone.  You'd just have to hope that your reverse engineer will give up.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. This is what I come up. So basically I cant hide it just make it bit complex for someone. is that same happen if its coded in native? different question perhaps.